# How to increase value of a button after button number has reached certain value?

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to create a set of buttons using java swing. I want to increase the button values with number 5 until they have reached 60. After that they should increase with the number 20. After 100 they should increase with 50. What is wrong with my for loop construct?

```
            ValueButton btn = new ValueButton((x + 1) * 5.0);
        for (int s = 0; s < btn.getValue(); s++) {
            if (btn.getValue() > 60.0) {
                  btn.setValue((x + 1) * 20.0);
                System.out.println("value: " + btn.getValue());
                if (btn.getValue() > 100.0) {
                    btn.setValue((x + 1) * 50.0);
                    System.out.println("value: " + btn.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
```

Buttons added to the interface:

```
  myButtons.add(btn, new GridBagConstraints(x % 4, y, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));
    }
```

Edited code based on Anand Kumar's answer:

```
        pnlValueButtons.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < 16; x++) {
            if (x % 4 == 0) {
                y++;
            }
                double buttonValue = 5.0;
            while (buttonValue <= 200) {
                ValueButton btn = new ValueButton(buttonValue);
                if (buttonValue < 60) {
                    buttonValue += 5.0;
                } else if (buttonValue < 100) {
                    buttonValue += 20.0;
                } else {
                    buttonValue += 50;
                }
      pnlValueButtons.add(btn, new GridBagConstraints(x % 4, y, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));
            }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the button value (we can only guess what it is) to increase continuously, as I believe the loop is suppose to do, or increment after every click ? For better help post [mre]

Comment: Increase continously. The idea is to create a total of 16 buttons wiht varying values. For example: 5,10,15,20,40,60,80,100,150,200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this a little differently.

[image: Increasing JButtons]

Since we know the values we want for the `JButtons`, I just put 16 values in an int array.  There's no need to calculate them, based on what the OP has told us so far.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class IncreasingJButtonExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new IncreasingJButtonExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Increasing JButtons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 4, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        Font font = panel.getFont().deriveFont(24f);

        int[] values = { 5, 10, 15, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 150, 200, 
                250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500 };

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(values[i]));
            button.setFont(font);
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            panel.add(button);
        }

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution works. Could you tell me how to set the constraints with the way i added them in code pnlValueButtons.add(btn, new GridBagConstraints value, value, value) (Example in last line of my code) as I am not familiar with Swing.

Comment: Basically the onlu problem i have now is that i cannot get the buttons to a row. Where do you set rows and how many buttons on row?

Comment: @WScoder: The two int parameters of the GridLayoput specify rows and columns.  Generally, you specify the column count and set the row count to zero, meaning any number of rows.  I'm not sure why you would want to use a GridBagLayout for a collection of JButtons.  Do you want them to be different sizes?

Answer (score 0):

```
pnlValueButtons.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
double buttonValue = 5.0;
for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < 16; x++) {
    if (x % 4 == 0) {
        y++;
    }
    ValueButton btn = new ValueButton(buttonValue);
    if (buttonValue < 60) {
        buttonValue += 5.0;
    } else if (buttonValue < 100) {
        buttonValue += 20.0;
    } else {
        buttonValue += 50;
    }
    pnlValueButtons.add(btn, new GridBagConstraints(x % 4, y, 1, 1, 0.0, 0.0, GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.NONE, new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1), 0, 0));
}
```

Comment: This solution propably doesn't work because the buttons get invoked only once. I added the line where buttons get invoked to the question.

Comment: This solution adds all the button values as 5.

Comment: Can you share modified code that has been done in your side

Comment: Shared on the question.